# Javascript Functions printing to same Span element

Tags: javascript, html

Beginner Javascript Student and stuck on something hopefully simple.

**I have two javascript functions that work as intended but both print to the same Span element even though they have different IDs.**

Cannot find a solution anywhere on SO or google.

Sorry it's a lot of code, don't know how else to display it.

https://jsfiddle.net/KrnRbts/dmeztkr0/

**Any help is much appreciated, cheers SO!**

JAVASCRIPT 1:

```
function calculateHeliSubTotal() {
    var adultCountHeli = document.getElementById("adultCountHelicopter"),
        childCountHeli = document.getElementById("childCountHelicopter"),
        infantCountHeli = document.getElementById("infantCountHelicopter"),
        adultCostHeli = 230,
        childCostHeli = 160,
        infantCostHeli = 0
    showSpan = document.getElementById('subTotalHelicopter');

    //changes the sub-total if the User changes the adult quantity
    function runAdultCountHeliEvent() {
        adultCountHeli.addEventListener('change', function () {
            getHeliSubTotal();
        });
    }

    //changes the sub-total if the User changes the child quantity
    function runChildCountHeliEvent() {
        childCountHeli.addEventListener('change', function () {
            getHeliSubTotal();
        });
    }

    //changes the sub-total if the User changes the infant quantity
    function runInfantCountHeliEvent() {
        infantCountHeli.addEventListener('change', function () {
            getHeliSubTotal();
        });
    }

    //calls to run the functions
    getHeliSubTotal();

    //a function that is used to run all of the events
    function runHeliEvents() {
        runAdultCountHeliEvent();
        runChildCountHeliEvent();
        runInfantCountHeliEvent();
    }

    //calls to run the functions
    runHeliEvents();

    //calculates the subtotal for the current service
    function getHeliSubTotal() {
        var adultHeliSubTotal = adultCountHeli.value * adultCostHeli,
            childHeliSubTotal = childCountHeli.value * childCostHeli,
            infantHeliSubTotal = infantCountHeli.value * infantCostHeli
        heliSubTotal = adultHeliSubTotal + childHeliSubTotal + infantHeliSubTotal;
        showSpan.innerHTML = '$' + heliSubTotal + ' ' + '(ex-GST)';
    }

}

calculateHeliSubTotal();
```

JAVASCRIPT 2: - Practically identical but different var values.

```
function calculateFWSubTotal() {
    var adultCountFW = document.getElementById("adultCountFixedWing"),
        childCountFW = document.getElementById("childCountFixedWing"),
        infantCountFW = document.getElementById("infantCountFixedWing"),
        adultCostFW = 530,
        childCostFW = 260,
        infantCostFW = 0
    showSpan = document.getElementById('subTotalFixedWing');

    //changes the sub-total if the User changes the adult quantity
    function runAdultCountFWEvent() {
        adultCountFW.addEventListener('change', function () {
            getFWSubTotal();
        });
    }

    //changes the sub-total if the User changes the child quantity
    function runChildCountFWEvent() {
        childCountFW.addEventListener('change', function () {
            getFWSubTotal();
        });
    }

    //changes the sub-total if the User changes the infant quantity
    function runInfantCountFWEvent() {
        infantCountFW.addEventListener('change', function () {
            getFWSubTotal();
        });
    }

    //calls to run the functions
    getFWSubTotal();

    //a function that is used to run all of the events
    function runFWEvents() {
        runAdultCountFWEvent();
        runChildCountFWEvent();
        runInfantCountFWEvent();
    }

    //calls to run the functions
    runFWEvents();

    //calculates the subtotal for the current service
    function getFWSubTotal() {
        var adultFWSubTotal = adultCountFW.value * adultCostFW,
            childFWSubTotal = childCountFW.value * childCostFW,
            infantFWSubTotal = infantCountFW.value * infantCostFW
        FWSubTotal = adultFWSubTotal + childFWSubTotal + infantFWSubTotal;
        showSpan.innerHTML = '$' + FWSubTotal + ' ' + '(ex-GST)';
    }

}

calculateFWSubTotal();
```

Comment: *"Sorry it's a lot of code, don't know how else to display it."* Try. See: [mcve]

Comment: showSpan is global variable, try this.showSpan

Comment: @MarekJanoud unfortunately no, both still calculate to the second Span element, thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`showSpan` is global in your variable declarations because you're missing a comma.

```
function calculateHeliSubTotal() {
  var adultCountHeli = document.getElementById("adultCountHelicopter"),
    childCountHeli = document.getElementById("childCountHelicopter"),
    infantCountHeli = document.getElementById("infantCountHelicopter"),
    adultCostHeli = 230,
    childCostHeli = 160,
    infantCostHeli = 0 // no comma, so a semicolon is automatically inserted
  showSpan = document.getElementById('subTotalHelicopter'); //global
// ...
}

function calculateFWSubTotal() {
  var adultCountFW = document.getElementById("adultCountFixedWing"),
    childCountFW = document.getElementById("childCountFixedWing"),
    infantCountFW = document.getElementById("infantCountFixedWing"),
    adultCostFW = 530,
    childCostFW = 260,
    infantCostFW = 0 //no comma, so javascript inserts a semicolon
  showSpan = document.getElementById('subTotalFixedWing'); //showSpan is overwritten

// ...
}
```

Add a comma to both of your methods and you're all set.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dmeztkr0/1/

Here's some information on JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion rules: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that was the problem but thanks a bunch for your time and info :)

Answer (score 1):

You're lacking a comma after

```
infantCostHeli = 0
```

So js engine is putting a ';' after it. The next line is:

```
showSpan = document.getElementById('subTotalHelicopter');
```

Will be interpreted as a new, single statement: so the showSpan declaration is lacking a 'var' identifier: so the showSpan variable is now a global variable, appended to the window object.

Sadly, the very same error exists in the second function with the infantCostFW variable:

```
infantCostFW = 0
```

So the second function is also referencing that global variable instead a local scoped, newly created 'showSpan' var.

So the call to calculateFWSubTotal() overrides showSpan global var value, and then both methods use that var when the listeners attached to change events in some DOM nodes fire. The events handlers inside the first function are fired after the calculateHeliSubTotal(), and they are consuming a global variables, so the fact that you define showSpan as

```
showSpan = document.getElementById('subTotalHelicopter');
```

doesn't matter to the event listeners defined inside calculateHeliSubTotal(.)

Just put an extra comma after the vars will do the trick. To use a linter like Eslint or JSlint will save you lots of similar problems.

Also, there's a lot of duplicity in your code, and the logics that calculates the values and register event handlers are really coupled. I think would be good for you post it in the code review stack exchange and seek for some advices.

Comment: Thanks for all the info Sergeon :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a config object that you pass into the function to allow reuse. This is taking advantages of closures in javascript that will lock in the environment around the event listeners so you can use them separately.

I also did a little refactoring of the stuff that is not necessary

```js
function calculateSubTotal(config) {
  var
    adultCount = document.getElementById("adultCount" + config.type),
    childCount = document.getElementById("childCount" + config.type),
    infantCount = document.getElementById("infantCount" + config.type),
    showSpan = document.getElementById('subTotal' + config.type),
    adultCost = config.cost.adult,
    childCost = config.cost.child,
    infantCost = config.cost.infant;
  
  // you don't need to wrap these events, you can just call
  // getSubTotal directly on change
  adultCount.addEventListener('change', getSubTotal);
  childCount.addEventListener('change', getSubTotal);    
  infantCount.addEventListener('change', getSubTotal);

  //calculates the subtotal for the current service
  function getSubTotal() {
    var 
      adultSubTotal = adultCount.value * config.cost.adult,
      childSubTotal = childCount.value * config.cost.child,
      infantSubTotal = infantCount.value * config.cost.infant,
      subTotal = adultSubTotal + childSubTotal + infantSubTotal;
    
    showSpan.innerHTML = '$' + subTotal + ' ' + '(ex-GST)';
  }
}

// init the total for helicopters passing in a config object
calculateSubTotal({
  type: 'Heli',
  cost: {
    adult: 230,
    child: 160,
    infant: 0
  }
})

// init the total for the other thing
calculateSubTotal({
  type: 'OtherThing',
  cost: {
    adult: 430,
    child: 160,
    infant: 0
  }
})
```

Comment: Config is a little beyond me atm but thanks for taking the time to help :)